# Use ng-href in chartkick for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, chartkick

Is it possible to use ng-href="{{userData}}" in chartkick for rails?  What I want to do is something like:

```
<%= line_chart ng-href='{{userData}}' %>
```

When my angular app loads up, I call .run like this:

```
kpiApp.run(function($rootScope, $http){
    $http.get('kpis/kpi_users_count.json').then(function (response) {
        $rootScope.userData = response.data;
    });
});
```

I can see it works because on my page {{userData}} renders the expected json, now I want to insert this as the data attribute as the chartkick documentation indicates:

```
<%= line_chart data, id: "users-chart", height: "500px" %>
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: You can't do this using ruby helper, ruby executes server side ages before angular kicks in. Chartkick gem is only a ruby wrapper for chartkick.js, if you want your chartkick working with angular, you need to use unwrapped version: https://github.com/ankane/chartkick.js. It is a chance to contribute - create angular module for chartick!

Comment: @BrioSatse, yeah, I think you're right.  What I ended up doing was creating an angular Directive with a link function to insert in a new chart on some $interval.  I just need it updated about every 15 mins, so that works ok.  thanks.